# Python Scrapy Xpath not following url

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am new at python and I am having a bit of trouble getting *scrapy* to follow urls. I suspect that it may be with the `xpath` specification, however after doing several tutorials on the topic, I am no closer to resolving this. It loops over the urls in the referenced table and scrapes the content from the starting page repetitively. What am I doing wrong?

Code attached:

```
import scrapy  
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider
from scrapy.spiders import Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.http import Request

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'unespider'
    allowed_domains = ['https://my.une.edu.au/']
    start_urls = ['https://my.une.edu.au/courses/']
    rules = Rule(LinkExtractor(canonicalize = True, unique = True), follow = True, callback = "parse"),    

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = Selector(response)
        for url in response.xpath('//*'):
        yield {
            'title': url.xpath('//*[@id="main-content"]/div/h2/a/text()').extract_first(),
            'avail': url.xpath('//*[@id="overviewTab-snapshotDiv"]/p[3]/a/text()').extract_first(),
               }       

        for url in hxs.xpath('//tr/td/a/@href').extract():
            yield Request(response.urljoin(url), callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: Well lots of issues are there. `allowed_domains` should have domain name and not url `allowed_domains = ['my.une.edu.au']`. The parse function should be inside the class. No need to use `hxs = Selector(response)`, In `LinkExtractor` your should give a pattern for the links you would like the spider to browser. `Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=("https://my.une.edu.au/courses/2017/courses/.+", ), canonicalize=True, unique=True), follow=True, callback = "parse_course")`. You should not override the `parse` method in a CrawlSpider. You should not yield Request in your function if the Rules do that

Comment: Thank you vert much for getting back to me; I have made the changes you suggested, however it exhibits similar behaviour; i.e. loops through the urls in the table, however now copies nothing - I have no idea what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

** update I see what you wanted and updated code, it now follows for each year and outputs correct**

I apologize that I'm not sure what your trying to follow and scrape from the start page as well as what this is //*[@id="overviewTab-snapshotDiv"]. I wasn't able to find that xpath. I'd like to help you out more since I'm fairly new as well to programming and scrapy was hard at first, I ended up making my own class scraper later so I could do it my way, even though I'm sure scrapy is better :)
I've done the code to scrape your titles and URLs, I commented out Rule since I don't know what your trying to follow or why.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import Rule

from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

from overflowQuestion2 import items #make sure to import items.py


class DavesimSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'daveSim'
    allowed_domains = ['my.une.edu.au']
    start_urls = ['http://my.une.edu.au/courses/2007', ] #start at 2007
    rules = Rule(LinkExtractor(canonicalize=True, unique=True), follow=True, callback="parse")


def parse(self, response): #This will scrape links and follow

    #Grab the main Div wrapping the links
    divLinkWrapper = response.xpath('//div[@class="pagination"]') 
    for links in divLinkWrapper: #for every element extract links
        theLinks = links.xpath('ul/li/a/@href').extract()
        for i in theLinks: #for every link, follow link
            yield scrapy.Request(i, callback=self.ContentParse)



def ContentParse(self, response): #scrape content you want

    #Grab main Div wrapper for content
    divMainContent = response.xpath('//div[@id="main-content"]')

    for titles in divMainContent:
        #create Item object from items.py function
        Item = items.Overflowquestion2Item() 
        theTitles = titles.xpath('div[@class="content"]//a/text()').extract()
        
        #set Item to the scrapy.Field in items.py
        Item['title'] = theTitles 
        yield Item #yield Item through pipeline

    for URLs in divMainContent:
        Item = items.Overflowquestion2Item()
        theURLs = URLs.xpath('//table/tr/td/a/@href').extract()
        Item['URL'] = theURLs
        yield Item
```

Now for items.py:

```
import scrapy


class Overflowquestion2Item(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = scrapy.Field()
    title = scrapy.Field()
    URL = scrapy.Field()

    pass
```

Also remember in settings to uncomment the items pipeline,

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'overflowQuestion2.pipelines.Overflowquestion2Pipeline': 300,
}
```

I'm positive this could be coded better and I hope someone here will refine it ;)

Comment: No it hasn't
It loops through the URLs for the table and copies the xpath from the starting page and doesn't follow the loops through